# How do I mock UserRecord internal class for Firebase unit testing with Moq

Tags: c#, firebase, unit-testing, moq

I want to write a unit test in C# using Moq for my code using Firebase SDK and specifically involving GetUserAsync(), e.g. UserRecord user = GetUserAsync(Uid) but am getting stuck on the Firebase UserRecord internal class. How do I mock the UserRecord class for testing given that it has read only internals?

What I've tried so far:

```
var firebase = new Mock<IFirebaseAppWrapper>();
firebase
  .Setup(x => x.GetUserAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
  .Returns<UserRecord>(usr =>
  {
    var item = new Mock<UserRecord>("1");
    return Task.FromResult(item.Object);
  });
```

Of course this doesn't work, but it feels close. Any advice?
BTW: The FirebaseApp has been artificially wrapped in a pass through class and has a counterpart interface class.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to return a mock of `UserRecord`? You could also create an instance and return this. `UserRecord` looks like a DTO so this should be fine.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand your answer Markus. Could you rework the example code to show what you mean? Thank you for helping :)

Comment: I thought of something like `.Setup(...).ReturnsAsync(new UserRecord() { /* Property initialization */});`. I'd only mock `UserRecord` if you want to assert that specific methods are called. A DTO does not have complex methods.

Comment: DTO = Data Transfer Object?

Comment: Unfortunately for your example, the class I am looking at only has the ability to set its contents via the constructor. Any normal property initialisation after the construction is not possible as sadly the property only has a getter: public string Uid { get; }. 

This is a Firebase specific issue that I've seen asked elsewhere on the internet and there were no answers there either :(

Comment: The UserRecord class does conform to an Interface "IUserInfo", but I also tried using that and couldn't figure out how to convert from a new object conforming to the interface, back to a UserRecord specific instance. 

If only Firebase had used an IUserRecord, I wouldn't be asking daft questions :)

Comment: Yes, if only :-) a bit of a hack for an emergency: you could create the instance using the constructor and access the internal properties using reflection.

Comment: Thank you Markus, you may be right there :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ReturnsAsync` method instead of `Returns`.

`Returns` is used for synchronous methods. On the other hand, if you want you specify the response for `async` methods after a call is awaited, you need `ReturnsAsync`.

Edit:

If `GetUserAsync` returns a `UserRecord` then you can just instantiate one:

```cs
firebase
  .Setup(x => x.GetUserAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
  .ReturnsAsync(new UserRecord("id"));
```

Comment: Thank you Mihail. I don't think that's the answer but it's certainly part of the puzzle, which is going help :)

Comment: check my edit, if you could further explain maybe I can help you :)

Comment: Unfortunately that will not compile, the UserRecord in firebase SDK has this constructor which I believe prevents the above from working:

internal UserRecord(GetAccountInfoResponse.User user)

and to make matters more "fun" the guts of that look like this (please excuse the formatting):

`code`
    internal sealed class GetAccountInfoResponse
    {
        internal sealed class User
`code`